# 2012 Volkswagen Polo Match DSG - are these dash startup lights normal?

Tags: vw, warning-light, polo

When I turn the key once (without starting the engine), these (attached) lights show. When I start the engine, they all go off. No problems with car, but should the EPC, battery and engine light show like this or is it a possible fault warning? Thanks.

[image: lights]

Comment: You are overthinking this. If you car starts, and no lights remain on, just go with it. If you are looking for a light to remain on, it's a VW, just give it time.

Comment: @cory - Don't be afraid to answer questions. Seems like you have some knowledge. I promise, with good answers come good rewards.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. The reason that the light come on is to give you proof that the lights are working. If you are truly conscientious you look them over with great care to ensure the lights are all showing :-)

More seriously some of the lights are actually telling you something, for example the ABS and airbag lights are set on when the controller starts its self-check and then are turned off if the self-check completes successfully. If the light were to stay on it would let you know that the system required service.

Others are just logical. Low alternator output is one of the conditions that illuminates an annunciator. When the engine isn't running the alternator output is zero and the lights comes on.

Comment: Great explanations here, dlu. Very logical and easy to follow. I like that you stated about the POST for the ABS. Also applies to SRS. If these don't come on at all, you'll fail a safety test for it as well.

Comment: SRS is the fancy name for the airbags?

Comment: YES! :o) ... SRS = Supplemental Restraint System

Comment: Cool, I learned something today :-)